# How to access an element inside a v-for loop using ref

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, v-for

To put as simply as possible:

I have a v-for loop. I'd like to access an specific element inside one of the iterations of the loop. For reasons, I can only do this using ref. Is there a way of doing this?

I have tried various different ways of achieving this, but it always returns undefined. My code works fine outside of a v-for loop.

The documentation for vue doesn't cover this instance.

The loop simplified:

```
  <div v-for="(item, i) in items">
    <div ref="card"></div>
  </div>
```

The Method

```
 doThing() {
   card = elements.create('card');
   card.mount(this.$refs.card);
 }
```

Answer (score 10):

Since array refs are not guaranteed to be in the original order, I've found it more helpful to register a ref on the parent, then use the regular DOM API to find the element you want.

#### Template

```html
<div ref="cards">
    <div v-for="(item, i) in items">
        <!-- this is a card -->
    </div>
</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```js
{
    methods: {
        getCardAt(index) {
            return this.$refs.cards.children[index];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
<div v-for="(item, i) in items">
    <div :ref="`card-${i}`"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This sounded interesting but I couldn't access that element using `this.$refs[`card-${i}`]`

Answer (score 0):

Refs in a `v-for` loop become arrays with each element at the index it appears in the document. It is covered here ~ https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref

> When used on elements/components with `v-for`, the registered reference will be an Array containing DOM nodes or component instances.

So to *"access an specific element inside one of the iterations of the loop"*, you would use something like

```
card.mount(this.$refs.card[someIndex])
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the order in that ref array is not guaranteed to be in the same order as the elements in the data array. This makes array refs pretty useless :(

Comment: @JosephSilber true but OP didn't say which specific element they want to reference. Maybe it's _any_ element?

Comment: Thanks, guys. I do need to access a specific element. Would it be possible to get the refs as an object (Using v-for="(item, key, index) in items" )? Then use the key to get the specific element?